# ILE RPG SQLStored Procedure set option for timestamp?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I want to create new records in RPG with a stored procedure.

First, I assign the values to every field of the table. For the Timestamp field it's

```
TSTPfield = %TIMESTAMP();
```

When I select the created records, every record's timestamp has three zeros at the end like 2018-06-14-11.01.31.028000.

If I create a record in a rpg program without the stoed procedure, the timestamp looks normal without the unnormal zeros.

What can I do to get a correct timestamp without zeros? Do I have to adjust the settings of the .sql file of the stored procedure? 
There I have defined these options:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exampleproc 
(
 **fields**
)    
LANGUAGE RPGLE
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
EXTERNAL NAME exampleproc GENERAL
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I create a record in a rpg program without the stoed procedure"

But RPG's [%timestamp() BIF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/bbtmst.htm) only supports 3 digits of decimal precision.

> Only the first three digits of the fractional seconds portion of the timestamp will be set to a non-zero value. The remaining fractional seconds will be zero.

Comment: thanks! now i fill the field with a short sql field = current timestamp, so i get 6 fracitonal seconds.

Comment: @nicowi note that recent releases support up to 12 digits of precision.  Also note that is's a bad idea to expect a timestamp to be  unique.  If you need a unique timestamp, consider using GENERATE_UNIQUE() instead.  It has an embedded timestamp and is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: how would you do it withe GENERATE_UNIQUE()? How can I assign it to my field? Can you give me an example? Thanks :)

Comment: You'd want to define your column `CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA`